# Unity camera follow on cylinder

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera

I have a mini project where a ball goes around a cylinder while moving forward on the cylinder. I want my camera to follow the ball and rotate towards the ball while in cameras point of view cylinder is always forward. So for example if the ball goes to the right i want the camera to follow the ball to the right but point at the cylinder all the time and not rotate with ball to the right
same problem like here:
https://answers.unity.com/questions/1680243/camera-follow-ball-along-cylinder.html

I have a code but doesn't work the way I want.

```
Transform target;
public Transform pos;
public float speed = 10f;
void Start(){
    //ball's transform
    target = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Player").transform;
}
void LateUpdate(){

    Vector3 rot = Quaternion.LookRotation (target.position - transform.position).eulerAngles;
    rot.z = 0;
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler (rot);


}
void FixedUpdate(){
    //sets the camera position to the position of the child object of the 
    //ball
    transform.position = pos.position;
}
```

Comment: What is the "Transform pos" set to in the editor? Also "target" is never used in setting the position of the camera, only the rotation. Perhaps you need something like "transform.position = target.position + new Vector3(0,0,0);" rather than "transform.position = pos.position;". But replace the "new Vector3(0,0,0);" with the  offset you want the camera to have in relation to the player. Please be more clear on how it is not working and how you want it to work.

Comment: https://answers.unity.com/questions/1680243/camera-follow-ball-along-cylinder.html i have same problem

Comment: You could make an empty game object that is positioned in the centre of the cylinder and write a script that sets the position of the empty game object (only on the axis parallel to the cylinder) to the position of the sphere. Then make the camera a child of the empty game object in the hierarchy.

Comment: You should probably name your fields better when posting any code here.
What is "Transform pos"? Is it Transform of your cylinder? So why don't you call it "cylinderTransform"? Same with "Transform target", rename it to "ballTransform" and your code is 372% more clear for us :) Naming is crucial in programing.